# Highlight top and bottom 10% in SSRS table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I want to highlight the Top and Bottom 10% of values in my SSRS Table.

The sample table should look like this - I have prepared below in Excel Sheet,

[image]

Is it possible in SSRS-2016?

Comment: so you just want to highlight using different color right? Also, it means above 90 should be Green and below 10 should be Red right?

Comment: yeah. but in terms of percentages. NOT just top N.

Comment: please check my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be achieve using below SQL query and SSRS expression.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT TOP (10) PERCENT MARKS,EmpName, 1 Ten FROM TableName ORDER BY MARKS
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (10) PERCENT MARKS,EmpName, 2 Ten FROM TableName ORDER BY MARKS DESC
)

SELECT m.EmpName,
       m.Marks,
       CASE 
            WHEN cte.Ten = 1 THEN 'Green'
            WHEN cte.Ten = 2 THEN 'Red'
            ELSE ''
       END RedGreen
FROM   TableName m
       LEFT JOIN cte
            ON  cte.Marks = m.Marks
```

Once dataSet is ready, we just need to set expression for Fill Color,

[image]

*Let me know if you need more help.*

Comment: This looks perfect. Just a confirmation - Can't we do this at a report level? Just like we have Top% operator at Tablix filter level?

Comment: I have never tried and I am not sure if it could be possible using expression. And I'm sure this will be easy for such requirements.

Comment: Welcome dude! Anytime!

Comment: Can we skip zero's ? Zero should be escaped from Bottom 10% of the values. Is it possible?